# Parse JSON that is list of dicts where values are also a list of dicts to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pandas

I'm pulling some data via the mailchimp export API and I'm struggling to come up with a speedy method to turn the contents into a Pandas dataframe.

The data is in the following format:

```
[{
u 'user1@email.co.uk': [{
    u 'action': u 'open',
        u 'ip': u '10.100.100.10',
        u 'timestamp': u '2015-02-22 21:50:54',
        u 'url': None
  }]
 }, {
u 'user2@email.co.uk': [{
    u 'action': u 'open',
        u 'ip': u '10.100.100.20',
        u 'timestamp': u '2015-02-22 20:05:28',
        u 'url': None
  }]
}, {
u 'user3@email.co.uk': [{
    u 'action': u 'open',
        u 'ip': u '10.100.100.30',
        u 'timestamp': u '2015-02-22 17:21:54',
        u 'url': None
  }]
}, {
u 'user4@email.co.uk': [{
    u 'action': u 'open',
        u 'ip': u '10.100.100.40',
        u 'timestamp': u '2015-02-22 17:48:00',
        u 'url': None
}, {
    u 'action': u 'open',
        u 'ip': u '10.100.100.50',
        u 'timestamp': u '2015-02-22 21:05:40',
        u 'url': None
}, {
    u 'action': u 'click',
        u 'ip': u '10.100.100.60',
        u 'timestamp': u '2015-02-22 21:05:45',
        u 'url': u 'http://www.thewebsite.com/content/'
}]
}]
```

I have a working version but this is way too slow to be viable for the amount of data I am working with:

```
for rec in resp:
  df = pd.DataFrame(rec[rec.keys()[0]])
  df['email'] = rec.keys()[0]
  df['campaign'] = campaign

master_df = pd.concat([master_df, df]) #precreated container
```

The output should look like:

[image]

Any suggestions welcome - I've experimented with a couple of the Pandas built in functions but without success.